# How get next row columns value in mysql loop over the cursor

Tags: mysql

I create stored procedure  in mysql which should select latitude, longitude values from table iterate over that result and calculate distance of 2 coordinates. 
How can I iterate over the select result and get current and next rows columns value like java ?

```
double d = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < locations.size-1; i++) {
    d += locations.get(i).getLat() + locations.get(i+1).getLat();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this my help 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html
You will find at Example 17.7 the loop over your procedure.